# Outer subtraction with Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-einsum

I simply want to do: C_i=\Sum_k (A_i -B_k)^2
I saw that this calculation is faster with a simple `for loop` than with the `numpy.subtract.outer`! Anyway I feel that `numpy.einsum` would be the fastest. I could not understand `numpy.einsum` that well. Can anyone please help me out? Additionally, it would be great if someone explains how a general summation expression consisting of vector/matrices can be written with `numpy.einsum`?

I did not find solution for this particular problem on the web. Sorry if duplicate in some manner.

MWE with loop and `numpy.subtract.outer`--

A)With loop

```
import timeit
code1="""
import numpy as np

N=10000;

a=np.random.rand(N); b=10*(np.random.rand(N)-0.5);

def A1(x,y):
    Nx=len(x)
    z=np.zeros(Nx)
    for i in np.arange(Nx):
        z[i]=np.sum((x[i]-y)*(x[i]-y))

    return z

C1=A1(a,b)"""
elapsed_time = timeit.timeit(code1, number=10)/10
print "time=", elapsed_time
```

B) With `numpy.subtract.outer`

```
import timeit
code1="""
import numpy as np

N=10000;

a=np.random.rand(N); b=10*(np.random.rand(N)-0.5);

def A2(x,y):
    C=np.subtract.outer(x,y);
    return np.sum(C*C, axis=1)

C2=A2(a,b)"""
elapsed_time = timeit.timeit(code1, number=10)/10
print "time=", elapsed_time
```

For N=10000 the loop becomes faster. For N=100, the outer subtract becomes faster. For N=10^5, outer subtract faces memory issue on my desktop with 8GB ram!

Comment: `einsum` is a generalization of the matrix product.  With a general set of dimensions is performs a sum of products on selected dimensions.  In other words it is `C_? = sum_? A_? * B_?`.

Comment: Thanks! I also found that the main purpose of `einsum` is multiplication. But still can we do the above summation with it? If not, what would be the optimised solution for these cases? `for` loop in python is very slow compared to that of C.

Comment: What are the typical sizes of the arrays `A` and `B`?

Comment: You `saw` the loop is faster than using `subtract.outer`?  where?  Can you demonstrate?  I would also test a variation on `outer` using broadcasting.

Comment: For my case the sizes are of the order 10^8. But I have to iterate this calculations a few times, so the speed matters a lot.

Comment: I will post a mwe soon

Comment: For array on the order of 1000, `subtract.outer` is clearly better, by a factor of 100.  Sometimes though when arrays sizes get very large, memory management involved in creating a (10^8, 10^8) size array eats into the efficiency of the vectorized outer.  In that case you could iterate on `i`, or blocks of `i`, while still using vectorized operations on `k`.  `einsum` even if worked, would not avoid this memory issue.

Comment: I somewhat agree. Please see the main question for MWE and timings with loop/outer subtract.

Comment: So is that it? For N>10^4 or 10^5, loop would be the best option?

Comment: There was an error in my answer. The result in A_nb_p_2 was wrong for array shapes not divideable by 1000. I corrected the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use at least Numba, or a Fortran Implementation

Both of your functions are quite slow. Python loops are very inefficient (A1), and allocating large temporary arrays is also slow (A2 and partially also A1).

**Naive Numba implementation for small arrays**

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@nb.njit(parallel=True, fastmath=True)
def A_nb_p(x,y):

    z=np.empty(x.shape[0])
    for i in nb.prange(x.shape[0]):
        TMP=0.
        for j in range(y.shape[0]):
            TMP+=(x[i]-y[j])**2
        z[i]=TMP

    return z
```

**Timings**

```
import time
N=int(1e5)
a=np.random.rand(N)
b=10*(np.random.rand(N)-0.5)

t1=time.time()
res_1=A1(a,b)
print(time.time()-t1)
#95.30195426940918 s

t1=time.time()
res_2=A_nb_p(a,b)
print(time.time()-t1)
#0.28573083877563477 s

#A2 is too slow to measure
```

As written above this is a naive implementation on larger arrays, since Numba isn't able to do the calculation blockwise, which leads to a lot of cache misses and therefore bad performance. Some Fortran or C- compiler should be able to do at least the following optimization (block-wise evaluation) automatically.

**Implementation for large arrays**

```
@nb.njit(parallel=True, fastmath=True)
def A_nb_p_2(x,y):
    blk_s=1024
    z=np.zeros(x.shape[0])
    num_blk_x=x.shape[0]//blk_s
    num_blk_y=y.shape[0]//blk_s

    for ii in nb.prange(num_blk_x):
        for jj in range(num_blk_y):
            for i in range(blk_s):
                TMP=z[ii*blk_s+i]
                for j in range(blk_s):
                    TMP+=(x[ii*blk_s+i]-y[jj*blk_s+j])**2
                z[ii*blk_s+i]=TMP

    for i in nb.prange(x.shape[0]):
        TMP=z[i]
        for j in range(num_blk_y*blk_s,y.shape[0]):
            TMP+=(x[i]-y[j])**2
        z[i]=TMP

    for i in nb.prange(num_blk_x*blk_s,x.shape[0]):
        TMP=z[i]
        for j in range(num_blk_y*blk_s):
            TMP+=(x[i]-y[j])**2
        z[i]=TMP

    return z
```

**Timings**

```
N=int(2*1e6)
a=np.random.rand(N)
b=10*(np.random.rand(N)-0.5)

t1=time.time()
res_1=A_nb_p(a,b)
print(time.time()-t1)
#298.9394392967224

t1=time.time()
res_2=A_nb_p_2(a,b)
print(time.time()-t1)
#70.12
```

Comment: Fun fact: after using `numba` the fans are so loud it made me afraid that the code may break the pc. I am using only 8gb of ram!