# How to speed up multiply and sum operations in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I need to solve a Finite Element Method problem and have to calculate the following `C` from `A` and `B` with a large `M` (`M>1M`). For example,

```
import numpy as np
M=4000000
A=np.random.rand(4, M, 3)
B=np.random.rand(M,3)
C = (A * B).sum(axis = -1) # need to be optimized
```

Could anyone come up with a code which is faster than `(A * B).sum(axis = -1)`? You can reshape or re-arrange the axes of `A`, `B`, and `C` freely.

Comment: If the einsum is still not fast enough also use Numba or Cython. This could give another factor of about 2,5 over einsum. A more complicated example with further optimizations which does not make sense here https://stackoverflow.com/a/58189944/4045774

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`np.einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) for a slightly more efficient approach, both in performance and memory usage:

```
M=40000
A=np.random.rand(4, M, 3)
B=np.random.rand(M,3)
out = (A * B).sum(axis = -1) # need to be optimized

%timeit (A * B).sum(axis = -1) # need to be optimized
# 5.23 ms ± 198 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit np.einsum('ijk,jk->ij', A, B)
# 1.31 ms ± 136 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

np.allclose(out, np.einsum('ijk,jk->ij', A, B))
# True
```

Answer (score 2):

To speed up numpy multiplication in general, one possible approach is using [ctypes](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ctypes). However, as far as I know, this approach probably will give you limited performance improvements (if any).

Answer (score 1):

You could use `NumExpr` like this for a 3x speedup:

```
import numpy as np
import numexpr as ne

M=40000
A=np.random.rand(4, M, 3)
B=np.random.rand(M,3)

%timeit out = (A * B).sum(axis = -1)
2.12 ms ± 57.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit me = ne.evaluate('sum(A*B,2)')
662 µs ± 13.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)


out = (A * B).sum(axis = -1)
me = numexpr.evaluate('sum(A*B,2)')
np.allclose(out,me)
Out[29]: True
```

Comment: I have tried both np.einsum and ne.evaluate. np.einsum is ~40% faster than ne.evaluate, but thanks for the hint!

Comment: Yes, as it is multi-threaded it will depend on your machine quite a lot. My Mac has 12 cores so it probably favours `numexpr` quite considerably.