# Using np.einsum to multiply and add two arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy arrays `p` and `s`:

```
p = np.ones((32, 64, 4, 1, 1))
s = np.ones((32, 1, 4, 512, 512))
```

and I want to do this operation:

```
x = p * s
x = np.sum(x, axis = 2)
```

This code describes exactly what I want to do, I want to multiply the arrays and sum them on the axis 2, but this solution has a **serious problem**, the `p * s` operation generates an array of shape (32, 64, 4, 512, 512) which takes up a *generous* amount of memory, and it is not really necessary, because in the next step I use `np.sum` in axis 2, so the ideal solution would be to multiply and add at the same time directly to the result (32, 64, 512, 512) array. I think it is possible to use np.einsum for this, but I would like some help with that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63667395/how-to-speed-up-multiply-and-sum-operations-in-numpy/63667494#63667494

Comment: I downvoted this because it's a textbook usage of einsum. You asked knowing which function to use and not reading the docs or bothering to make an actual attempt to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, using np.einsum will be much much faster:

```
p = np.ones((32, 64, 4, 1, 1))
s = np.ones((32, 1, 4, 512, 512))
x = np.einsum('abcde,abcde->abde',p,s)
```