# Efficiently avoid large intermediate array in computation?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have two arrays `p` and `alpha`, and I want to `<=`-compare each element of `p` with each element of `alpha`, and then aggregate (count) over the first axis. My code:

```
s = np.sum(np.less_equal.outer(p, alpha), axis=0)
```

`p` is at least one- but possibly multidimensional, and can have dimensions like 100 × 1000000. `alpha` is one-dimensional and has typically 100 to 1000 elements.

The problem is that `np.less_equal.outer` creates an intermediate array, which in the worst case can be of size 100 × 1000000 × 1000 = 10<sup>11</sup> elements, close to 1 TB, far beyond my memory capacity.

My approach is to split the computation up along the first axis:

```
s = np.zeros(shape=(*p.shape[1:], len(alpha)), dtype='int64')
for pr in p:
    s += np.less_equal.outer(pr, alpha)
```

That seems to work, but I'm wondering whether NumPy has tools to make this more efficient (vectorized)?

Comment: What we call 'vectorized' in `numpy` is that first approach, making the large intermediate array.  That's using the compiled numpy methods, and for modest size arrays is fast.  But  with larger cases memory management becomes more complex and slows that down.  Then a modest number of iterations on a relatively complex task is better.  Unless you want get into compilation tools like `numba`.

Comment: @hpaulj so since I'm iterating over the shortest axis, that means my solution is as efficient as it gets (without compilation)?

Comment: Probably.so.   Only timings can prove it.

Comment: PS: By 'vecorized' I meant a compiled routine that is equivalent to my combination of `sum` and `*.outer`, without actually generating the intermediate array.

Comment: I guess the easiest way (and a lot faster) is to write it down in a simple loop and use Cython or Numba for compilation. This will avoid any temporary array. This is quite similar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58189944/4045774

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In numpy increasing the blocksize may help, but it is also quite straight-forward to implement the algorithm in compiled code. I used Numba here, but with a few changes it should also work in Cython.

**First Try**

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb
@nb.njit(fastmath=True)
def outer_cust(p,alpha):
    res=np.zeros((p.shape[1],alpha.shape[0]),dtype=np.int64)
    for i in range(p.shape[0]):
        for j in range(p.shape[1]):
            for k in range(alpha.shape[0]):
                if p[i,j]<=alpha[k]:
                    res[j,k]+=1
                else:
                    res[j,k]+=0
    return res
```

This method does not use any temporary arrays. Nevertheless the memory access isn't aligned (assuming C-contiguous arrays). Therefor the performance will be not really good, but already faster than the numpy algorithm.

**Second Try**

```
@nb.njit(fastmath=True,parallel=True,cache=True)
def outer_cust_2(p,alpha):
    #p should be fortran ordered to avoid memory copy
    p_T=np.ascontiguousarray(p.T)
    res=np.empty((p.shape[1],alpha.shape[0]),dtype=np.int64)
    for j in nb.prange(p_T.shape[0]):
        for k in range(alpha.shape[0]):
            acc=0
            for i in range(p_T.shape[1]):
                if p_T[j,i]<=alpha[k]:
                    acc+=1
            res[j,k]=acc
    return res
```

In this method a memory copy is needed if the input is c-ordered. But the memory access is aligned which offers a high speedup, especially on large arrays. It is also easily parallelize-able.

**Timings**

```
#Smaller arrays
p=np.random.rand(1000,10000)
alpha=np.random.rand(1000)
%timeit outer_cust_np(p,alpha)
#20 s ± 580 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit outer_cust(p,alpha)
#5.56 s ± 61.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit outer_cust_2(p,alpha)
#166 ms ± 1.19 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

#Maximum size
p=np.random.rand(1000,1000000)
alpha=np.random.rand(1000)
%timeit outer_cust_np(p,alpha)
#too slow to measure
%timeit outer_cust(p,alpha)
#too slow to measure
%timeit outer_cust_2(p,alpha)
#24.2 s ± 1.52 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: That looks very good! I had no idea it was that simple to have compiled functions in NumPy.

Comment: @A. Donda I used another package here (Numba). Basically it determines the types, creates LLVM-IR and compiles that using LLVM. The last two steps are quite similar to Clang.

Comment: Gret answer :) just to understand it better, why in the first try the memory access is not aligned? I am impressed that it helps a lot in the second try.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are generating data for some downstream computation. If that particular downstream computation can be done in parts, then you can just go column by column, save the result to disk, and merge the results later.

Another approach is to get the required parts of this large matrix on demand during the downstream computation using indexed operations on p and alpha.

I would prefer the second approach for simplicity reasons.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is an extremely vague answer. I laid out the context completely, there's no need to speculate about downstream computations.